# eigen value with 2 eigen vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I got a question to solve for complex eigen value and eigenvector of the following matrix:
A=
$
\begin{pmatrix}
-7 & 4 \\
-9 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$
. 
I worked it out and obtained eigen value $-1$ which I wrote as $
i^2
$. but then it gives 2 eigen vectors but is it possible to have $2$ eigen vectors for $1$ eigen value?

Comment: It's possible, but that eigenvalue has only one linearly independent eigenvector.

Comment: $-1$ is indeed an eigenvalue, but why do you write that eigenvalue as a square? There seems to be no obvious reason to go that way.

Comment: but it asked to solve for complex eigen values of A,and hence calculate the complex eigenvectors of A.

Answer (score 1):

the characteristic polynomial of $A=\pmatrix{-7&4\\-9&5}$ is $det(A+\lambda I) = (\lambda+1)^2.$ so $A$ has one one eigenvalue $-1$ repeating. the null space of $A+I$ has dimension $1$ and an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue is $u = \pmatrix{2\\3}.$ you can find a generalized eigenvector $v = \pmatrix{-1\\-1}$ satisfying $(A+ I)v = u.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It simply scales the plane $span(v_1, v_2)$ by a $-1$ factor.

Or, differently, if im not wrong, the plane $span(v_1, v_2)$ is being reflected to the line given by: $span(v_1+v_2)=\alpha (v_1+v_2) = \alpha 
 w$